# How to use type alias in interface

Tags: go

Consider the following program:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type MyMethod func(i int, j int, k int) (string, error)

type MyInterface interface {
  Hello(i int, j int, k int) (string, error)
}

type myMethodImpl struct {}

func (*myMethodImpl) Hello(i int, j int, k int) (string, error) {
   return fmt.Sprintf("%d:%d:%d\n", i, j, k), nil
}

func main() {
    var im MyInterface = &myMethodImpl{}
    im.Hello(0, 1, 2)
}
```

How do I use MyMethod in the interface declaration instead of repeating the method signature?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are mixing two different things here. The one is that you define a type which is a function. When you want that type inside another type you need to use a struct.

Changing your code to a possible solution 1 (not so idiomatic go):

```
type MyMethod func(i int, j int, k int) (string, error)

type myMethodImpl struct {
    Hello MyMethod
}

var hello MyMethod = func(i int, j int, k int) (string, error) {
    return fmt.Sprintf("%d:%d:%d\n", i, j, k), nil
}

func main() {
    im := &myMethodImpl{Hello: hello}
    fmt.Println(im.Hello(0, 1, 2))
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/MH-WOnj-Mu

The other solution would be to change it to use an interface. That solution is your code just without the type definition of MyMethod. https://play.golang.org/p/nGctnTSwnC

But what is the difference between?

If you define a func as a type you need to declare it, when you create a function.

```
var hello MyMethod = func(i int, j int, k int) (string, error) {
    return fmt.Sprintf("%d:%d:%d\n", i, j, k), nil
}
```

Now `hello` has just exactly the type `MyMethod`. If there would be another type for example:

```
type YourMethod func(i int, j int, k int) (string, error)
```

`hello` will still just the type `MyMethod`.

To define an interface you need a [method set](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Method_sets). But the type `MyMethod` is not a method. It is just a [function type](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Function_types). So the function type is something different then a method definition. For go it would be the same if you want to define a string as a method.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I don't think it answers my question entirely. May be I did not ask the right question. Is So there no way to share method signature? The whole point of my question was that I have a method with large at of parameters. Can I avoid repeating it when I want to define interfaces and types. ? I'm taking about using it in multiple interfaces and structs.. It looks like there is no way to achieve it from your reply if I read it right.

Comment: I don't think that it is possible to define a type as a method in Go. Why should it? Such a mixing would make the code just unreadable.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I will use struct embedding as you suggested if needed.